# Post does not disappear

Tags: customization

The teaser of a deleted post is still sticking in one of my blog category lists (in one of two that the post was assigned to).

I have tried to optimize DB tables. I have restored (through Vaultpress) to a time before the post was created. I have emptied the cache. I use Cloudflare but turned it off suspecting it might be related to that. I have disabled all plugins. But the teaser will not go a way.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you go into the control panel > Posts, do you see a small link for "Trash" at the top of the list of posts? If so go to that and 'Empty trash' / permanently delete the post. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved it self "spontaneously". My best guess is that is was some kind of cached information that was lingering. Perhaps related to Cloud Flare